# How to move jquery-ui slider with CasperJS

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there any way to move the [jQuery UI – Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org) ?

I also found this [github issue](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/211) while searching for a possibility to just click on the left or right of the slider to move the *handle*. But this doesn't worked for me as well.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To move the slider works as follows:

```
casper.mouse.down(100,100);
casper.mouse.move(200,200);
casper.mouse.up(200,200);
```

with

```
casper.capture('test1.jpg');
```

called before and after the three mouse lines you should see the differene.

Comment: You should combine it with [casper.getElementBounds](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementbounds) to have a generic solution, because you cannot know where the slider is at all times or rather it is cumbersome to know.

Comment: sure. I just wanted to show how to move something with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete demo:

```
// test_slider.js

var casper = require('casper').create(),
    mouse = require('mouse').create(casper),
    utils = require('utils');

casper.start('http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/default.html')
      .then(function() {
        var slider = this.getElementBounds('.ui-slider');
        var handle = this.getElementBounds('.ui-slider-handle');

        this.echo('=== BEFORE ===', 'INFO');
        this.echo(this.getElementAttribute('.ui-slider-handle', 'style'));
        this.capture('before.png');

        this.echo('=== DRAGGING ===', 'INFO');
        this.mouse.down('.ui-slider-handle');
        this.mouse.move(slider.left + slider.width / 2, slider.top + slider.height / 2);
        this.mouse.up('.ui-slider-handle');

        this.echo('=== AFTER ===', 'INFO');
        this.echo(this.getElementAttribute('.ui-slider-handle', 'style'));
        this.capture('after.png');
      })
      .run();
```

#### Result

```
$ casperjs test_slider.js
=== BEFORE ===
left: 0%;
=== DRAGGING ===
=== AFTER ===
left: 50%;
```