# CasperJS: Simulate swipe-event

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I tried to build a few casperjs tests. Went well so far but at one thing I failed:

**Building a test for a swipe-event.**

I need something like this:

```
casper.mouse.down("#myelement"); // press and hold mousebutton
casper.mouse.move_x(200); // Move mouse 200 to the right
casper.mouse.up(); // Release mousebutton
```

But there is no function like move_x in the casper-docs.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How did it fail? Do you have a sample page where we can try it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. Yes the function "move_x" is what i'm looking for. Or another method to do this

Comment: Related: [How to move jquery-ui slider with CasperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176369/how-to-move-jquery-ui-slider-with-casperjs)

Comment: Have you figured out an answer? Even if you don't, please provide a negative answer.

Comment: Actually: I isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own move_x method by getting the coordinates of the selector and using these as modified inputs to mouse.move(x + selector.x, selector.y).

Some people still believe this does not work. Try the following snippet:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.mouse.down('div.some_selector');
    this.mouse.move(200, 100);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.mouse.up(200, 100);
});
```

Comment: I had the same answer. It was downvoted and I deleted it 19 hours ago. It doesn't work according to OP: "*Thank for for that suggestion. But it doesn't work. I figured out, that PhantomJS does not hold any button when moving the mouse (see: http://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/147). :-(*"

Comment: Can you provide a complete script as a paste/gist? I haven't found good swipe example page.