# Testing JQuery-UI Slider in Casper.js

Tags: jquery-ui, casperjs, functional-testing

I have a slider created using JQuery-UI which has 4 slider segments. The structure is something like this:

```
<div id="mySlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all disabled">
  <div class="ui-slider-segment" title="1">
  <div class="ui-slider-segment" title="2">
  <div class="ui-slider-segment" title="3">
  <div class="ui-slider-segment" title="4">
</div>
```

Initially the slider has the 'disabled' class. When I click on any segment of the slider, it triggers the slideChange event and the event handler which I wrote for that event removes the class 'disabled'. This works as expected in Chrome and Firefox browsers.

My problem occurs when I test this in casper.js. I've tried the following one after the other without success.

I followed the solution posted here: [How to move jquery-ui slider with CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176369/how-to-move-jquery-ui-slider-with-casperjs)

```
//left and top co-ordinates of the segments fetched using element.getBoundingClientRect()
this.mouse.down(242.890625,488.75); 
this.mouse.move(214.46875,403.9375);
this.mouse.up(214.46875,403.9375);
```

I can't use CSS3 selectors for the triggering mousedown in casper.js, as there are no IDs for the segments, and every segment has the same classes (dynamically generated by JQuery-UI).

```
  var slide = casper.evaluate(function(){
        var sliderId = $('#mySlider');
        sliderId.slider('value',2);
  });

  casper.then(function(){
    var sliderClass = casper.evaluate(function(){
      return document.getElementById('mySlider').className;
    });
    console.log(sliderClass); //still contains the class 'disabled'
  });
```

Where am I going wrong? I've included both jquery and jquery-ui libraries. Is there any other way?

Comment: You cannot drag/swipe with CasperJS alone: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/147

Comment: Related: [CasperJS: Simulate swipe-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844113/casperjs-simulate-swipe-event)

Comment: Of course you can use CSS selectors to trigger mousedown on those elements `title` is an attribute and can be used for selection: `#mySlider > div[title="2"]` or even positional `#mySlider > div:nth-child(2)` through `document.querySelector`. But what does this give you?

Comment: I didn't know this could be done. Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: I tried casper.click('#mySlider > div[title="2"]'). It shows FAIL Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector:#mySlider > div[title="2"]

Comment: @ArtjomB. My bad. I did not use the selector properly. Now it doesn't show any error but the class name isn't changing either.